# How to insert table between 2 server in Azure data warehouse?

Tags: sql, azure, azure-sql-database, etl

I want to insert table from different factory / server in Azure data warehouse. Is it possible to insert by query?

Because it takes a lot of time if I make dataset and pipeline for each table in Azure data factory.

[image]

Comment: Hi Leon, Sorry for late respon. I have found a feature in azure that can copy all the data with looping each table in a lookup. Check this out https://analytics-blog.com/2019/09/24/copy-multiple-tables-in-azure-data-factory/

Answer (score 0):

Just from your screenshot, according the icon of the Azure SQL, you're using Azure SQL database, not Azure Data Warehouse.

You could use [Elastic Query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/elastic-query-overview) to do a cross database query in Azure.

Ref the tutorial: [Get started with cross-database queries (vertical partitioning) (preview)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/elastic-query-getting-started-vertical)

Elastic database query (preview) for Azure SQL Database allows you to run T-SQL queries that span multiple databases using a single connection point. This article applies to vertically partitioned databases.

When completed, you will: learn how to configure and use an Azure SQL Database to perform queries that span multiple related databases.

Then you can inset data from external table to current database table.

Note: Azure SQL database already has the master key, you don't need create it again.

Hope this helps.